# How to get environment variable PS1 by golang?

Tags: bash, go, environment-variables

PS1 is an environment variable for bash prompt. I can get this by `echo $PS1`

I try to use [os.Getenv](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) to get `PS1` but returns nothing:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Println(os.Getenv("PS1"))
}
```

Why does this happen and how should I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: is the variable actually set? doesn listing `os.Environ` show you a `PS1=value` pair?

Comment: I can get it by `echo $PS1`

Comment: are you starting the process (I mean running that go program) with the same user?

Comment: Yes. I found that i cannot get PS1 by `env | grep PS1` but can get it by `set | grep PS1`. Is there any difference?

Comment: yes, `set` sees shell local and environment variables, `env` sees only environment variables (which are passed to child processes). If you don't see it in `env` then your go programme won't be able to use it, you need to properly export it. You can check SO for more detailed explanation of `env` vs `set`.

Comment: Thanks~ Can you reply this to my post then i can approve your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PS1 is probably not exported, meaning it won't show up in sub-processes of bash

try

```
export PS1
```

before you run your app

you could also do

```
PS1=$PS1 app
```

to set it specifically in the sub process

Comment: This is sh/bash specific. The csh family of shells (including zsh?) have a different syntax for the former and the portable, shell agnostic, way to do the later is `env VAR=val command…`