# How to read Linux environment variables, in Go

Tags: linux, go

I'm trying to read env variables, to store passwords outside my code for example. Tried setting it up in `.bashrc` and also in `/etc/environment`, no luck:

```
func Test_env(t *testing.T) {
    variable, exists := os.LookupEnv("SOME_PASS_ENV")
    log.Printf("%v%v", variable, exists)
}

=== RUN   Test_env
2020/11/06 12:26:07 env_value:  exists?: false
```

The variable is available globally after setting it up in `/etc/environment`. What else can I do? Thanks.

Just in case, `getEnv("SOME_PASS_ENV")` returns nothing, that's why used `LookupEnv` to check.

Comment: If the value is not returned from `os.LookupEnv` or `os.Getenv`, then it is not set in the environment. This has nothing to do with Go itself.

Comment: are you sure the value was loaded? If you only just changed /etc/environment it might take a restart of your environments to get this loaded. Better don't depend on your system for your tests. You should define the variables in your test configuration. Manually you could do in bash: `SOME_PASS_ENV=test_value /path/to/compiled-go-binary`

Comment: If you do fmt.Println(os.Environ()) it shows you the env with the value? if not try with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364178/how-to-get-environment-variable-ps1-by-golang

Comment: @jim not fully related but tangentially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [os.Getenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) to get the value of an environment variable when you don't need distinguish empty environment variable value versus unset environment variable.

```
func Getenv(key string) string
    Getenv retrieves the value of the environment variable named by the key. It
    returns the value, which will be empty if the variable is not present. To
    distinguish between an empty value and an unset value, use LookupEnv.
```

Use [os.Lookupenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lookupenv) when you do need to distinguish empty environment variable value versus unset environment variable.

```
func LookupEnv(key string) (string, bool)
    LookupEnv retrieves the value of the environment variable named by the key.
    If the variable is present in the environment the value (which may be empty)
    is returned and the boolean is true. Otherwise the returned value will be
    empty and the boolean will be false.
```

Use [os.Environ](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Environ) to get the list of all environment variables and their values.

```
func Environ() []string
    Environ returns a copy of strings representing the environment, in the form
    "key=value".
```

---

Side note: maybe you're not setting the environment variable correctly. Try setting with `export SOME_PASS_ENV=some_value` directly in your shell prior to you running your `go test`

Comment: Thanks! Checked and now it's obvious that the variable is not properly detected in the system. I already set it up in /etc/envirioment and also in .bashrc, where else can be set?

Comment: I just added the Side note to the answer above. try that, and see if that works. It should.

Comment: No luck. But the thing here is that I'm doing the things right Go-wise. Will accept this answer as it helps to debug and look elsewhere for help about how to properly set the env so it's readable by my test.

Comment: Are you using a shell? or are you using an IDE? If it's the latter, that may be the problem.

Comment: Doing `export ENV_VAR_123=abc` then running `go build` from a git bash terminal window, where the first line of the module is `MyVar, ok = os.LookupEnv("ENV_VAR_123")` returns an error...
`undefined: MyVar`. It's very frustrating. Any insights?